# Getting countries of UEFA Champion's league teams (Java)

Tags: java, jsoup

I used JSoup to load certain teams (the first 2 from each group (A-H) from UEFA Web and now I need to add to the each team their nationality.
Here's the code I made (not finished yet but it doesn't matter now) :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2016/standings/index.html").get();


        Elements rank1 = doc.select("tr.on.rank_1");

        String array = rank1.text();
        array = array.replaceAll("-", "");
        array = array.replaceAll("\\d", "");


        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array.split("          ")));


        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));

        }
```

... and the output is :

```
Real Madrid CF
VfL Wolfsburg
Club Atlético de Madrid
Manchester City FC
FC Barcelona
FC Bayern München
Chelsea FC
FC Zenit
```

... it should look like e.g :

```
Real Madrid CF, Spain
```

The problem is that there is no info about country in the string I'm parsing.
And no I cannot label all the teams with their countries as I need to work with older seasons too, because year is the input to the program. (I'll make dynamic URL later - that is no problem). 
Any ideas how to do that?
Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: You could scrape the country of a club from this Site: http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2016/clubs/country/index.html

Comment: Could you please feature an example in accordance with the code I posted?

Comment: The easiest would be to create a map of team and country. There aren't many teams so it's not a big job. And the team name don't change that often :)

Comment: In the time you've written the question, you could've labeled all the 32 teams with their countries already. On the site you've linked, you could also start another web request on the link of the team and get the nation from there eg http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2016/clubs/club=50051/index.html

Comment: I forgot the mention that the input is the year.. (I will make dynamic URL later)
So it's not just about 2015 season, it can be any season before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to scrape all possible Clubs by Country and use this as a kind of database. Therefore scrape the website and store all countries with their clubs in a `Map<String, List<String>>` e.g.:

```
Map<String, List<String>> clubs_by_country = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
URL url = new URL("http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2016/clubs/country/index.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
//class for all different countries
Elements elements = doc.select("div.contcountry.generalcont");
for(Element element : elements){
    //scrape the country name
    String country = element.select("h3").first().select("img").first().attr("title");
    Elements teams = element.select("tr[class~=(on|off)]");
    List<String> clubs = new LinkedList<String>();
    //scrape all club names
    for(Element team : teams){
        clubs.add(team.select("a").first().attr("title"));
    }
    clubs_by_country.put(country, clubs);
}
```

Comment: Nicely done, Thank you! And now I just have to compare this Map with my arraylist?

Comment: Basically Yes, you could consider creating a little class eg: `class Club` with `String country` and `String club_name` as attributes and replace the `Map<String, List<String>>` with a simple `List<Club>`. This would make comparing easier or even smarter: switch `Key` and `Value` of your Map and make `Map<String, String>` where your `Key` is the club name and your `Value` is the Country. Then you could simply use the built-in `get(Object key) : Value` method of your Map and you don't need extra comparing at all ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, you've really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

The page you try to get the information doesn't have it, it will make your job way harder than it needed to be. I suggest you use another page. Take a look a [this one](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2016/clubs/country/index.html): It gives you every team, separated by country. If you want to get only teams that reached the group stage, you can get the information from [this page](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2016/clubs/round=2000634/index.html). It also has the country but in a slightly different way.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The problem is that I don't need just teams that reached group stages but I need the first 2 teams from each group. Just like on the site I'm parsing datas from. The page you featured contains all teams in group stage, however there's not information about which 2 from each group I should load :/ ...